# Vue-cli build modifica el path de archivos estáticos

Tags: vuejs, vue-cli

Estoy migrando un sitio web ***HTML*** puro a un proyecto ***vue-cli***, pero al lanzar el `build` para subirlo al servidor (`vue-cli-service build`) siempre transforma mal la ruta de los estáticos. Si prefijo la ruta de cada uno con `'./'` los reconoce bien, pero conforme el proyecto va incluyendo mas imágenes se va convirtiendo en un problema asegurarse de modificar todas estas rutas a mano

¿Puede ser por la estructura del proyecto o en la ruta definida para acceder a estos ficheros?

Ejemplo de cómo se está definiendo la ruta de los estáticos actualmente

```
<img src="../assets/imagen.jpg" />
```

Este es el `package.json` del proyecto ***Vue.***

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Y la estructura del proyecto

```
-dist
-js
  |-script.js
-libs
-node_modules
-public
-src
  |-assets
  | |-imagen.jpg
  |-components
  |-App.vue
  |-main.js
```

Un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un proyecto de Vue, tú tienes tus archivos de desarrollo en una ruta por ejemplo los `assets`, pero al usar el comando `build` Webpack genera el `bundle` de una forma que desestabiliza la estructura de rutas.

Por lo que entiendo tu problema está en las imagenes. la solución es lo siguiente:

Debes convertir esto:

```
<img src="../assets/imagen.jpg" />
```

a esto

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/imagen.jpg')">
```

ahí están pasando 3 cosas nuevas para tu código de imagen original que pones de en tu pregunta.

- src ahora es un atributo enlazado (v-bind) para poder declarar js dentro
- está la función `require` la cual sirve para traer algo de otra ruta
- en vez de poner `../` pones `@/` donde `@` es un alias de `src` pero sólo se puede usar en desclaraciones de js por eso es necesario utilizarlo todo en conjunto, así cuando hagas el build, webpack pondrá la ruta correcta en tus imagenes

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el código HTML está en el archivo `App.vue`, mueve tu carpeta de `assets` un nivel arriba, algo como esto:

```
-assets              <-- La nueva ubicación de assets y las imagenes
|-imagen.jpg
-dist
-js
|-script.js
-libs
-node_modules
-public
-src
|-components
|-App.vue
|-main.js
```

O si quieres mantener el orden predefinido, pon tu código HTML en componentes dentro la carpeta `components`.